# In Python, is the method to load objects part of the class?

Tags: python, csv

I want to read a text file, manipulate the fields a bit, and load them into instance variables for an object. Each row of the text would be stored in one object, so reading the whole file should return a list of objects.

Here's an example of the file:

```
L26 [coords]704:271[/coords] (1500)
L23 [coords]681:241[/coords] (400)
L20 [coords]709:229[/coords] (100)
```

And here's part of the current class definition:

```
class Poi(object):
    '''Points of Interest have a location, level and points'''

    def __init__(self, level, coords, points):
        self.level = level
        self.coordinates = coords
        self.points = points
```

I'm new to this, and probably overthinking it by a lot, but it seems like the method to read and write the list of Pois should be part of the Poi class. Is there a correct way to do that, or is the right answer to have a separate function like this one?

```
def load_poi_txt(source_file, source_dir):
    poi_list = []
    pass
    return poi_list
```

Comment: `pass` doesn't do anything. If you want a function to do something, `pass` will generally not be involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct, depending on what you want. Here's the method skeleton:

```
class Poi(object):
   ...
  @classmethod
  def load_from_txt(cls, source_file, source_dir):
    res = []
    while (still more to find):
      # find level, coords, and points
      res.append(cls(level, coords, points))
    return res
```

Note how it uses `cls`, which is the class the method is defined on. In this case it is `Poi`, but it could just as easily be a subclass of `Poi` defined later without needing to change the method itself.

Comment: And suddenly my code feels elegant again. Thank you!
For those new to class objects, you call this with my_poi_list=Poi.load_from_txt('myfile', 'mydir')